# Writing an image's ColorSync profile on a Mac

Tags: python, macos, steganography, color-profile

I'm making an lsb-steganography project and one issue is that the image's the program outputs are different in color to the original image when nothing is changed (rgb values are the same), and I found the reason to be because the new images being generated dont have an LCD profile as their color profile.

So far I have this code to access the image's 'ColorSync profile':

```
def get_image_color_sync_profile(image_path: str) -> str:
    result = os.popen(f'sips -g profile {image_path}').read()
    return result
```

which gives me the string
`/Users/xxxxxxxxxx/Desktop/xxxx.png profile: Color LCD` (x's are personal info but have the same length)

However I'm struggling with changing the characters of the string (the ones that mention the color profile).
If I have an image with another profile, I have the string s = `/Users/xxxxxxxxxx/Desktop/xxxx.png profile: something_else`
and I want to change s[37:] to 'Color LCD' but I get various errors such an unknown error and `Error: Profile at profile: Color LCD Color LCD cannot be opened Error: Invalid replacement profile Error 13: an unknown error occurred Try 'sips --help' for help using this tool`

Any tips on how to edit the color profile of an image on Mac using python?

I've tried simply replacing the color profile text since it's a string however it does not allow that. I was expecting the color profile in the string to change.

Answer (score 0):

A colour profile is a chunk of data; it cannot be replaced by a textual operation.

It *may* be possible to copy the profile from the original image, by using `sips -x foo.dat orig.png` to extract the profile, and `sips -e foo.dat new.png` to embed it into the new image.